# How to rout back to domain/home to domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes

Here is my example:

```
myApp::Application.routes.draw do
get "main/home" 
match 'home/', to: 'main#home', via: :get
root :to => 'main#home'
```

What I need to is when the user types www.mywebsite.com/home redirect him back to www.mywebsite.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what version of Rails you are using, but on Rails 4+:

```
get '/home', to: redirect('/')
```

See the [Routing Redirection docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection) for more detailed info.